# Bind delete key in vi mode

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using the vi-mode plugin of oh-my-zsh. In my `.zshrc`, I have

```
bindkey '^[[3~' delete-char
```

where `^[[3~` is the escape code of my delete key. However, this only works in insert mode, but not in command mode. When I type

```
$ abcd
```

move the cursor to the beginning of the line and hit `del` in command mode, I get

```
$ ABCd
```

so apparently the character sequence of the delete key is interpreted literally. How can I make the delete key actually delete a character in command mode?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
bindkey -a '^[[3~' delete-char
```

Zsh has a variety of different keymaps and by default, bindkey will bind keys in the normal insert mode keymap. The command mode keymap is selected with `-M vicmd`. `-a` is a shortcut for that. You can list the keymaps with `bindkey -l`. You'll see that there is also `viopp` which is used for movements after a key like c or d. There's also visual for visual selection mode.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2020 now, and I'm not sure if @okapi 's answer is out of date or just missing a piece, but for me, I had to use:

`bindkey -a '^[[3~' vi-delete-char`

`delete-char` without the `vi-` prefix didn't do the trick but adding it did.